# Successfully implemented threading, but I cannot figure out how to write results to file

Tags: java, multithreading, io, filewriter

So, I have the program doing what I want. Using threading to encrypt the passwords has turned a 15 minute task into a 2 minute task. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to write the encrypted passwords to a file. I figured I would have every thread store its result in an array and then I planned on writing the contents of the array out to a file to a file. This doesn't seem to be working at all and I'm not sure why.

I know the code if very sloppy, but I'm just trying to get a working solution before I try to pretty things up.

Thanks!

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.Thread;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;



class encryptThread extends Thread {
   private Thread t;
   private String threadName;
   private long[] password_aes;
   private String uh = "";
   private static final char[] CA = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".toCharArray();
   private static final int[] IA = new int[256];
   private int j = 0;


    static {
        Arrays.fill(IA, -1);
        for (int i = 0, iS = CA.length; i < iS; i++)
            IA[CA[i]] = i;
        IA['='] = 0;
    }

   encryptThread( String name, int i){
       threadName = name;   
       j = i;
   }

   public void run() {
    String finalString = "";
    String[] parts = threadName.split(":");
    password_aes = prepare_key_pw(parts[1]);
    uh = stringhash(parts[0], password_aes);
    finalString = (parts[0] + ":" + parts[1] + ":" + uh + "\n");
    //System.out.println(finalString);
    PassArray.passwordArray[j] = finalString;

    if (j == 176) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 500; x++) {
            System.out.println(PassArray.passwordArray[x]);
        }
    }
   }

   public void start ()
   {
      System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
      if (t == null)
      {
         t = new Thread (this, threadName);
         t.start ();
      }
   }

    public static long[] str_to_a32(String string) {
        if (string.length() % 4 != 0) {
            string += new String(new char[4 - string.length() % 4]);
        }
        long[] data = new long[string.length() / 4];

        byte[] part = new byte[8];
        for (int k = 0, i = 0; i < string.length(); i += 4, k++) {
            String sequence = string.substring(i, i + 4);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try {
                baos.write(sequence.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
                System.arraycopy(baos.toByteArray(), 0, part, 4, 4);
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(part);
                data[k] = bb.getLong();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                data[k] = 0;
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    public static String a32_to_str(long[] data) {
        byte[] part = null;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            bb.putLong(data[i]);
            part = Arrays.copyOfRange(bb.array(), 4, 8);
            bb.clear();
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(part);
            while (bais.available() > 0) {
                builder.append((char) bais.read());
            }
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static byte[] aes_cbc_encrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key) {
        String iv = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
        byte[] output = null;
        try {
            SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NOPADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
            output = cipher.doFinal(data);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static long[] aes_cbc_encrypt_a32(long[] idata, long[] ikey) {
        try {
            byte[] data = a32_to_str(idata).getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
            byte[] key = a32_to_str(ikey).getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
            byte[] encrypt = aes_cbc_encrypt(data, key);

            return str_to_a32(new String(encrypt, "ISO-8859-1"));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new long[0];
    }

    public static String base64_url_encode(String data) {

        try {
            data = new String(base64_url_encode_byte((data.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")),true), "ISO-8859-1");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        data = data.replaceAll("\\+", "-");
        data = data.replaceAll("/", "_");
        data = data.replaceAll("=", "");

        return data;
    }

    public static String a32_to_base64(long[] a) {
        return base64_url_encode(a32_to_str(a));
    }

    public static String stringhash(String email, long[] aeskey) {
        long[] s32 = str_to_a32(email);
        long[] h32 = {0, 0, 0, 0};
        for (int i = 0; i < s32.length; i++) {
            h32[i % 4] ^= s32[i];
        }
        for (int r = 0; r < 0x4000; r++) {
            h32 = aes_cbc_encrypt_a32(h32, aeskey);
        }
        long[] h32Part = new long[2];
        h32Part[0] = h32[0];
        h32Part[1] = h32[2];
        return a32_to_base64(h32Part);
    }

    public static long[] prepare_key(long[] password) {
        long[] pkey = {0x93C467E3, 0x7DB0C7A4, 0xD1BE3F81, 0x0152CB56};
        for (int r = 0; r < 0x10000; r++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < password.length; j += 4) {
                long[] key = {0, 0, 0, 0};
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    if (i + j < password.length) {
                        key[i] = password[i + j];
                    }
                }
                pkey = aes_cbc_encrypt_a32(pkey, key);
            }
        }
        return pkey;}

    public static long[] prepare_key_pw(String password) {
        return prepare_key(str_to_a32(password));
    }

       public final static byte[] base64_url_encode_byte(byte[] sArr, boolean lineSep){
            // Check special case
            int sLen = sArr != null ? sArr.length : 0;
            if (sLen == 0)
                return new byte[0];

            int eLen = (sLen / 3) * 3;                              // Length of even 24-bits.
            int cCnt = ((sLen - 1) / 3 + 1) << 2;                   // Returned character count
            int dLen = cCnt + (lineSep ? (cCnt - 1) / 76 << 1 : 0); // Length of returned array
            byte[] dArr = new byte[dLen];

            // Encode even 24-bits
            for (int s = 0, d = 0, cc = 0; s < eLen;) {
                // Copy next three bytes into lower 24 bits of int, paying attension to sign.
                int i = (sArr[s++] & 0xff) << 16 | (sArr[s++] & 0xff) << 8 | (sArr[s++] & 0xff);

                // Encode the int into four chars
                dArr[d++] = (byte) CA[(i >>> 18) & 0x3f];
                dArr[d++] = (byte) CA[(i >>> 12) & 0x3f];
                dArr[d++] = (byte) CA[(i >>> 6) & 0x3f];
                dArr[d++] = (byte) CA[i & 0x3f];

                // Add optional line separator
                if (lineSep && ++cc == 19 && d < dLen - 2) {
                    dArr[d++] = '\r';
                    dArr[d++] = '\n';
                    cc = 0;

                }
            }

            // Pad and encode last bits if source isn't an even 24 bits.
            int left = sLen - eLen; // 0 - 2.
            if (left > 0) {
                // Prepare the int
                int i = ((sArr[eLen] & 0xff) << 10) | (left == 2 ? ((sArr[sLen - 1] & 0xff) << 2) : 0);

                // Set last four chars
                dArr[dLen - 4] = (byte) CA[i >> 12];
                dArr[dLen - 3] = (byte) CA[(i >>> 6) & 0x3f];
                dArr[dLen - 2] = left == 2 ? (byte) CA[i & 0x3f] : (byte) '=';
                dArr[dLen - 1] = '=';
            }
            return dArr;
        }


    }


public class TestThread {


   final static String OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = "C:\\combo_encrypted.txt";

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, Throwable {


      for (int f = 0; f < 500; f++){
          PassArray.passwordArray[f] = "haddy ma'am";
      }


      File file1 = new File("File1.txt");
      File file2 = new File("File2.txt");
      File file3 = new File("File3.txt");
      File file4 = new File("File4.txt");

      FileInputStream fis1 = null;
      FileInputStream fis2 = null;
      FileInputStream fis3 = null;
      FileInputStream fis4 = null;

      BufferedInputStream bis1 = null;
      BufferedInputStream bis2 = null;
      BufferedInputStream bis3 = null;
      BufferedInputStream bis4 = null;

      DataInputStream dis1 = null;
      DataInputStream dis2 = null;
      DataInputStream dis3 = null;
      DataInputStream dis4 = null;

      fis1 = new FileInputStream(file1);    
      fis2 = new FileInputStream(file2);
      fis3 = new FileInputStream(file3);
      fis4 = new FileInputStream(file4);

      bis1 = new BufferedInputStream(fis1);
      bis2 = new BufferedInputStream(fis2);
      bis3 = new BufferedInputStream(fis3);
      bis4 = new BufferedInputStream(fis4);

      dis1 = new DataInputStream(bis1);
      dis2 = new DataInputStream(bis2);
      dis3 = new DataInputStream(bis3);
      dis4 = new DataInputStream(bis4);

      int i = 0;

      while ( (dis4.available() != 0) ) {
          encryptThread[] threadList = new encryptThread[4];




            String combo1 = dis1.readLine();
            String combo2 = dis2.readLine();
            String combo3 = dis3.readLine();
            String combo4 = dis4.readLine();


            threadList[0] = new encryptThread(combo1, i);
            threadList[1] = new encryptThread(combo2, i);
            threadList[2] = new encryptThread(combo3, i);
            threadList[3] = new encryptThread(combo4, i);

            threadList[0].start();
            threadList[1].start();
            threadList[2].start();
            threadList[3].start();


            /*
            RunnableDemo R1 = new RunnableDemo(combo1, array1, i);
            RunnableDemo R2 = new RunnableDemo(combo2, array2, i);
            RunnableDemo R3 = new RunnableDemo(combo3, array3, i);
            RunnableDemo R4 = new RunnableDemo(combo4, array4, i);

            R1.start();
            R2.start();
            R3.start();
            R4.start();
            */
            i++;
      }

      fis1.close();
      fis2.close();
      fis3.close();
      fis4.close();

      bis1.close();
      bis2.close();
      bis3.close();
      bis4.close();

      dis1.close();
      dis2.close(); 
      dis3.close(); 
      dis4.close(); 

      System.out.println(PassArray.passwordArray[5]);
   }   
}

class PassArray {
    public static String[] passwordArray = new String[500];

}
```

Comment: Can you tell me exactly which variable is to be written to the output file?

Comment: And where, do you think, this happens?

Comment: Ahs N, the variable finalString is what I need written to the output file.

Comment: @pelayo Don't use an array for one. Create a shared static threadsafe collection (such as `List<String> passwordList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());`) and have the threads add the final String there. Your code is quite poor and could use some refactoring, overriding `start()` in `Thread` is a bad idea as well.

Comment: You should implement Runnable rather than extends Thread.

Comment: yeah, this is fishy:   public void start ()
   {
      System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
      if (t == null)
      {
         t = new Thread (this, threadName);
         t.start ();
      }
   }

Comment: Is the problem that you want to write output from all threads to one file in a threadsafe way? If so, does that order of output matter - ie can the output line of one thread be interleaved with the output of another thread?

Comment: @Bohemian, order of output doesn't matter in this case. The results can be printed to the file in any order.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following codes:

```
PrintWriter file =  new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, true)));
file.println(finalString);file.close();
```

...right before the line of code `PassArray.passwordArray[j] = finalString;` in your *thread*.

Edit: Remove the previous codes from the main thread.

Comment: This simply prints "haddy ma'am" to the file.

Answer (score 0):

there's a problem here where you are passing `this` into new Thread(). Maybe the Thread API supports it, but I don't think it's very standard.

```
 public void start ()
       {
          System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
          if (t == null)
          {
             t = new Thread (this, threadName);
             t.start ();
          }
       }
```

as one of the commenters pointed out:

```
  class encryptThread extends Thread
```

should become

```
 class EncryptThread implements Runnable
```

then you do

```
 new Thread(new EncryptThread()).start();
```

when you pass an instance of a class that implements Runnable, or in shorter terms, an instance of Runnable (they are the same) into the Thread constructor, then when you call .start() it actually kicks off in the .run() method of the Runnable instance.